# What functions can access a global variable that appears in the same file with them?

Tags: c++, function, global-variables, global

I asked ChatGPT and Google Bard a C++ question that **"What functions can access a global variable that appears in the same file with them?"**

They answered that "Any function within the same file where the global variable is declared can access that global variable. Global variables have program-level scope, which means they are accessible from any part of the program within the same program (file). **Whether a function is defined before or after the global variable declaration, it can still access and modify that variable.**"

I was expecting that I can access the global variable in a function defined before the declaration of global variable but I am not able to access it. IDE throws this error:

> error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
> cin >> x;

Did ChatGPT and Google Bard answered wrong or there is any other problem with my code?

**My code :**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int myFun()
{ 
    return x*2;
}
int x;
int main() {
    cout << "Enter value in global variable: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << myFun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Hallucinate](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/cambridge-dictionary-names-hallucinate-word-of-the-year-2023). AI sometimes just makes things up.

Comment: ChatGPT is wrong (who knew?). Global variables can only be referenced after their declaration.

Comment: The internet is full of misconceptions about C++, the same errors come up again and again. Relying on and AI which has been trained on the collective 'wisdom' of the internet seems a little risky. I suggest you obtain a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/), one written by experts who know what they are talking about and who know how to comminucate that to learners.

Comment: A function can access a global variable before it has been **defined** (or even if the definition is not present at all) but not before any **declaration**. Why not ask ChatGPT about the difference between a definition and a declaration, or better still, ask an expert.

Comment: @john it says the function can be defined before the variable declaration. Thats not correct

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, I've deleted my last comment, I reread and misread the original quotation.

Comment: ""error: 'x' was not declared in this scope cin >> x;" This is not what is wrong in your code. Is that really the error message you get? Please find the output tab and include the complete compiler error message in the question.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this question. The question itself is ok, the problem I see is that the actual question ("can I access the global variable before it is declared?") is hidden behind a wall of not really useful bot gibberish, and when that is put aside not any research effort has been made. Really no offense, but it is important to understand that chat bots cannot be a reliable first and only source of information. And if your question was actually that, "can I trust what chat bots tell me?" this isnt ontopic here

Comment: All of your code can access all of your global variables. That's what being a global variable means. The code has to know that the global variable exists, so there has to be a **declaration** before it's used. that's what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is the complete error message from gcc for your code (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kx1Pecxc7)):

```
<source>: In function 'int myFun()':
<source>:5:12: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
    5 |     return x*2;
      |            ^
```

Nothing more. And gcc is correct. You cannot use `x` before it has been declared. C++ code is parsed top to bottom (templates aside). There is no other mistake in your code.

`cin >> x;` should not be an error, because it appears after you declared `x`.

Chat bots can assist you but they can not teach you how a language works. Do not rely on what they say to gain knowledge.